# JQuery Validation - Print message when field is valid

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

With the [JQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/) is it possible to print 'Ok' when the field is correct? When there's an error, I can show a customizable error message. Is the same thing possible when there's no error in the field and it's content is valid (I mean it's not empty) ?

### UPDATE

Here's an example of what I want to achieve : [Example](http://passport.nexon.net/Registration/Signup.aspx?nexonTheme=Dungeonfighter). When the value of the field is correct, a checkbox image appear at the right of the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Plugin's `valid()` method to see if the field validates, and display your message if it returns true.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid

Comment: This function validate the whole form. What I would like is to validate each field individually. Ideally, I would like to have something as easy as to add error message.

Comment: Only the example provided at the link above validates the whole form. The selector can be anything you want, including a single field.